# I can't convey data from fetch for express API

Tags: javascript, express, asynchronous, async-await, fetch-api

I have a problem that I don’t understand how to solve, it should work, but it doesn’t.

```
const getPhones = async () => {
  await fetch(url, requestOptions)
    .then((response) => response.text())
    .then((XMLdata) => {
      const parser = new XMLParser()
      const jObj = parser.parse(XMLdata)
      let data = jObj['soapenv:Envelope']['soapenv:Body']['ns:listPhoneResponse']['return']['phone']
      console.log(data)
      return data
    })
    .catch((error) => console.log('error', error))
}
```

the function returns JSON like this, I can see it in `console.log(data)`:

```json
[
  { name: 'SEP805E0C47A189', model: 'Third-party SIP Device (Basic)' },
  { name: 'SEPDCEB94CE9A65', model: 'Cisco 7821' },
  { name: 'TCT-442001', model: 'Cisco Dual Mode for iPhone' },
  { name: 'BOT-441015', model: 'Cisco Dual Mode for Android' },
  { name: 'SEP70708B219FC8', model: 'Cisco 8851' },
]
```

then everything is the same as everyone else export import express

```
export const phonesData = (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).json(getPhones)
}

router.get('/api/phones', phonesData)
```

but when I go to the page localhost:3000/api/phones I get a 200 response but the data that I see in the console is missing. I copied the data from the `console.log` into a constant, and tried to substitute the constant in export, the data appeared. The function `getPhones` is asynchronous, it waits for fetch to be executed, then the result is parsed by fast-xml-parser into JSON which is returned.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getPhones` is a *function*:

```
const getPhones = async () => {
```

Here you're trying to return the function itself, rather than invoking it:

```
export const phonesData = (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).json(getPhones)
}
```

You can *invoke* (call) a function by adding *parentheses* to it.  Note also that `getPhones` is an `async` function, so you need to `await` its result:

```
export const phonesData = async (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).json(await getPhones());
}
```

Or, if an `async` version of `phonesData` doesn't suit your needs, you can follow the result with `.then()`:

```
export const phonesData = (req, res) => {
  getPhones().then(data => res.status(200).json(data));
}
```

Either way, you need to *call* the function in order for it to execute and return its result.

---

**Additionally**, mixing `await` and `.then()` is a recipe for bugs:

```
const getPhones = async () => {
  await fetch(url, requestOptions)
    .then((response) => response.text())
    .then((XMLdata) => {
      const parser = new XMLParser()
      const jObj = parser.parse(XMLdata)
      let data = jObj['soapenv:Envelope']['soapenv:Body']['ns:listPhoneResponse']['return']['phone']
      console.log(data)
      return data
    })
    .catch((error) => console.log('error', error))
}
```

If you want to use `await` syntax, use `await` syntax:

```
const getPhones = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(url, requestOptions);
    const XMLdata = await response.text();
    const parser = new XMLParser();
    const jObj = parser.parse(XMLdata);
    let data = jObj['soapenv:Envelope']['soapenv:Body']['ns:listPhoneResponse']['return']['phone'];
    console.log(data);
    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('error', error);
  }
}
```

Alternatively, in lieu of `await` you can return the `Promise` chain.  In which case the function doesn't need to be `async`:

```
const getPhones = () => {
  return fetch(url, requestOptions)
    .then((response) => response.text())
    .then((XMLdata) => {
      const parser = new XMLParser()
      const jObj = parser.parse(XMLdata)
      let data = jObj['soapenv:Envelope']['soapenv:Body']['ns:listPhoneResponse']['return']['phone']
      console.log(data)
      return data
    })
    .catch((error) => console.log('error', error))
}
```

In both cases the consuming code would treat it the same way, since both return a `Promise` which would resolve to `data` (or fail and log the error to the console).

Comment: Thank you for your help, I did different things and nothing. Your edits don't work either. As I wrote above, when I simply pass a constant with identical data to the API, everything works fine. And I am 90% sure that fetch also works correctly and the XML parser also works correctly, otherwise I would not see the data in the correct format in console.log before return data. Even if I missed async / away somewhere, I would see something like Promise (pending)

Comment: Moreover, when I update the localhost:3000/api/phones page, I see in the VSCode console how console.log (data) from the getPhones function is processed correctly

Comment: @JohnDow: *"I am 90% sure that fetch also works correctly"* - You should debug/test/validate to be 100% sure, otherwise you may be chasing down the wrong bug.  And indeed it's certainly possible that **other** bugs/mistakes may exist in your code, perhaps in code you're not showing us.  Or perhaps you've made mistakes or false assumptions in your testing.  But one thing is absolutely certain... You need to **invoke** the function in order to get its result.  If you've corrected this problem and are facing another problem, can you update the question?

Comment: You will not believe! I changed it to Axios and it worked!

Comment: Your complete answers are very valuable to me. I am very grateful to you for the new rule for me, not to mix async / await with then, and also for the example with Promise.

Answer (score 0):

This is very strange, but I changed fetch to axios and everything worked for me.

```
async function makeRequest() {
  try {
    const response = await axios.request(config)
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data))
    const parser = new XMLParser()
    const jObj = parser.parse(response.data)
    const data = jObj['soapenv:Envelope']['soapenv:Body']['ns:listPhoneResponse']['return']['phone']
    console.log(data)
    return data
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
}
```

Comment: This has less to do with fetch vs. axios and more to do with how you re-structured this function (and, presumably, invoked the function).  This is no longer using `.then()` syntax and forgetting to return the Promise chain, but is now entirely using `await` syntax and returning the result.  The same change would work with fetch as well.

Comment: @David You are a wizard), this actually works in both your fetch and Promise variant! Thanks to your help, I began to understand these processes more))). Have a nice day to you. Great job!